# How can I find devices using port X in the local network?

Tags: ios, swift, tcp

There may be one or the other professional in the topic of **TCP** connections in **iOS**.

The user of my app can configure and connect a network device in the app. To connect the device, I want to show the user a list of available devices. However, I would only like to display devices with a specific port there.

I really hope that someone can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "match a specific port"? Do these devices have a TCP server listening on this port? Please add more info to the question

Comment: @SuyashMedhavi Example: I have a network printer and this printer always has the same port. I would now like to display all printers with this port in a list.

Basically, I only need one way to query all network devices from my Lan and then to filter them by port. But I haven't found a library where you can see the port.